# Why is my ANTLR 4 parser rule not returning the desired value?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to use ANTLR 4.3 with the antlr4-maven-plugin of the same version to achieve two goals:

1. Validate a user provided expression against a fairly simple grammar to prevent injection of invalid or potentially dangerous code.
2. Rewrite identifiers in the expression such that they are fully qualified using dot notation, e.g. `context.identifier`.

I am having problems with item 2. Because I only need to make very minor modifications to the input expression, using a parser rule with a return value seems like the appropriate solution. However, the parser returns the original identifier rather than the rewritten one that I would expect to see.

Here's simplified version of the grammar to illustrate the behavior:

```
grammar Sample;

expr
 : ( field_name ) EOF
 ;

field_name returns [String fqn]
 : any_name { $fqn = "prefix." + $text; }
 ;

any_name
 : IDENTIFIER
 | STRING_LITERAL
 | '(' any_name ')'
 ;

IDENTIFIER
 : '"' (~'"' | '""')* '"'
 | '`' (~'`' | '``')* '`'
 | '[' ~']'* ']'
 | [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*
 ;

STRING_LITERAL
 : '\'' ( ~'\'' | '\'\'' )* '\''
 ;
```

The field_name rule is intended to prepend a qualifier to any name it encounters and return the fully qualified name. However, in my test this never seems to work:

```
package sample;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.BailErrorStrategy;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ParserRuleContext;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.TokenStream;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SampleParserTest {

    @Test
    public void testSampleParser() {
        CharStream input = new ANTLRInputStream("field1");
        SampleLexer lexer = new SampleLexer(input);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        SampleParser parser = new SampleParser(tokens);
        BailErrorStrategy errorHandler = new BailErrorStrategy();
        parser.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
        ParserRuleContext tree = parser.expr();
        TokenStream tokenStream = parser.getTokenStream();
        String fqn = tokenStream.getText(tree);
        assertEquals("prefix.field1", fqn);
        // org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[prefix.]field1> but
        // was:<[]field1>
    }

}
```

What's wrong with my grammar or the unit test that prevents the field_name rule from returning the expected fully-qualified name? Are there other (better) ways to achieve the same goals?

Thanks in advance for your time and expertise.